# Javascript, two async/await and promise func but one is working and the other is not working

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

my utils.js have two funcs. i using in the electron@2.0.2.

```
async function detectMimeType(filePath) {
    let detectMime=new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          // mmmagic npm module
          magic.detectFile(filePath, function(err, result) {
               if (err) reject(err);
               resolve(result);
          });
    });

    let result = await detectMime;

    return result;
}

async function parseXML(data) {
    let parse = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // xml2js npm module
        parser.parseString(data,function(err,xmldata){
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(xmldata);
        });
    });

    let result = await parse;

    return result;
}
```

**detectMimeType** func returning result. but **parseXML** func returning Promise object pending.

```
let mime = detectMimeType('testingSound.mp3'); // returning 'audio/mpeg';
let xmlPayload = 
    parseXML('<root><test>testData</test></root>'); //returning Promise object pending
```

but it works like this.

```
async function init(){
    let xmlPayload = 
    await parseXML('<root><test>testData</test></root>');
}
```

Why does not it work like detectMimeType?

**UPDATE:** detectMimeType and parseXML two func returning Promise Object.
async functions always return a Promise.

Comment: `detectMimeType` can’t return `"audio/mpeg"`, since it’s an `async` function which can only return a Promise. Are you sure you haven’t overridden the definition of `detectMimeType` somewhere?

Comment: `async` functions **always** return a `Promise`

Comment: `let mime = detectMimeType('testingSound.mp3'); // returning 'audio/mpeg';` this is **impossible**. Please check your **actual** code and **actual** output carefully

Comment: @Xufox Nope. never in a place I didn't override it.

Comment: @JaromandaX ok, I'il go over it again.

Comment: yes; detectMimeType returning promise object. I missed it. thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Functions declared as `async function` always return promises, even if their body is completely synchronous:

```
async function foo() {
    // seemingly synchronous code
    return "bar!";
}

const a = foo(); // Promise<pending>
const b = await foo(); // "bar!"
```

Whatever you return from the `async` function, is passed to the either `resolve()` or `reject()` function of the implicit promise that has been created as the result of `async function` invocation.

So, you have always `await foo()` for the result, or use `foo().then()` if you are forced to use callbacks.

In general case, `return await promise` is merely a self-documentating construct, effectively equivalent to `return promise`, because promise would be in any case awaited as part of the implicit return promise resolve process.

Also, given your intent, I'd suggest promisifying your functions using standard Node.js `util.promisify` or `Bluebird.promisify` (whichever is available to you):

```
const { promisify } = require('util');

const detectMimeType = promisify(magic.detectFile);
const parseXML = promisify(parser.parseString);
```

This keeps them functionally equivalent to the code you have produced already, but restraints from excessive use of `new Promise()`, generally frowned upon.